# After Effects: Bend and animate along path

Tags: adobe-after-effects, animate

I have been looking for a way to bend and animate an object along a path and I stumbled upon the [**Omino plugin**](http://omino.com/pixelblog/2014/04/13/omino-plugins-2-1-for-after-effects/) [omino snake to be precise] and after preparing the scene I realized nothing's happening [ :)) ].

I can't get it to work while the plugin doesn't give any errors. Everything is set in place, I have the path as a mask on a solid and the objects that I want to animate inside a pre-comp, exactly as needed.

Almost all of the options of the omino snake plugin do nothing, the only thing that works is the *clear background* feature.

Is there a way to fix this? Is there something else I need to do? Or is there another way to animate and bend something along a path?

[image]

> **PS:** Copying a Mask Path and pasting it over the Position of the
>   pre-comp won't help cause it will animate it along the path but it
>   can't bend it.
>
> **PSS:** Using the Puppet Pin Tool to shape the pre-comp in the final position and animating the pre-comp contents isn't exactly a nice way
>   to do it cause the Puppet Pin Tool is hard to manoeuvre and often the
>   final result isn't satisfying.

### UPDATE

The closest I could get to something decent is using the Puppet Pin tool and transform each pin into a Bone inside Duik and rigging it as a tail. But for some reason, animating this will produce artefacts :

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? Would you mind posting an answer if yes?

Comment: #Luciano Yes I did! I will post an answer these days! I am on holiday leave right now and can't get access to my files to put a propper answer

Comment: @Alin any update?

Answer (score 1):

From 26m30s of this School of Motion tutorial is an explanation of using Omino Snake to bend a brush stroke along a path.

May be of use.

https://www.schoolofmotion.com/tutorials/write-on-after-effects

Comment: Please consider adding an excerpt of the technique demonstrated in the video you're linking to.  As-is, your answer is totally dependent on the link. Since link rot is rampant, we prefer answers that incorporate the knowledge in the actual answer body. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Cool - I'll see if that's possible as it's a fairly involved explanation as I remember it!